# MAMP Multiple hosts, php versions, and ddns

Tags: php, mamp, virtualhost, hosts, mamp-pro

I'm using MAMP Pro v4.4 on an iMac running High Sierra. I need to provide remote access to sites. The document root is htdocs for all my sites. I use no-ip.com for DDNS. It all works fine. Locally and remote, no problem.

I'm trying to setup another host and eventually assign it another version of PHP if I can get that far. I don't know what I'm missing but I just don't get it. I follow the docs. Create the new host name and choose the document root folder which is in the htdocs folder.

For example, on my local machine it works fine. http://testhost:8888 resolves properly. But http://other.ddns.net:8888/testhost does not. In fact none of the ddns works now even the ones that had been working.

Not sure what I'm missing? Or doing wrong? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Update the Joomla install for security reasons.  **Especially** since it needs older PHP, which is also likely end of life / near end of life.

Comment: That's not the issue, forget about Joomla and forget about the PHP version for the moment. Creating any new host is the issue. I'm testing with a simple index.html file. As soon as I create the new host the whole DDNS system fails.

Comment: When you come to a community of developers and present your situation, and it includes things that have [potentially horrible security consequences](https://blog.sucuri.net/2017/05/sql-injection-vulnerability-joomla-3-7.html), I'm afraid we can't "forget about them" as you suggest.  You will at _least_ get a comment (and, honestly, you should welcome the comments).  You want everything on a [minimum of PHP 5.6](http://php.net/supported-versions.php), and should consider being on 7.2+

Comment: I appreciate your concern. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my question so as to narrow the focus.